# Does the set of all 3x3 echelon form matrices with elements in R form a subspace of M3x3(R)? Same question for reduced echelon form matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

[Screenshot of the past exam question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9drB.png)

Firstly, the zero 3x3 matrix denoted as A is both in echelon and reduced echelon form since it satisfies both definitions respectively.

$$
        A = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Question 1: Are 3x3 echelon form matrices closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Question 2: Are 3x3 *reduced* echelon form matrices closed under addition and scalar multiplication?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking whether these collections of matrices are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Have you tried some examples for either collection?

Comment: Got it! Echelon form matrices form a subspace while reduced echelon form matrices do not... I'm pretty sure, right?

Answer (score 1):

Reduced echelon form matrices most certainly do not form a vector space, as $ I_3 $ is in reduced echelon form, and yet $ 2 I_3 = I_3 + I_3$ is not, so it is closed under neither addition nor scalar multiplication.

The set of matrices in echelon form do not form a vector space either: consider

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

The third column contains a leading $ 1 $, and yet it has other nonzero entries, which means that it is not in echelon form, and yet the summands are.

Comment: Hold on.

But isn't the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} 

in echelon form since the zero rows (if any) occur at the bottom _and_ each leading (non-zero) entry in a row is in a column to the right of the leading
entry of the row above it?

Comment: It doesn't work with your definition either: consider
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
If you required the matrix entries to be nonnegative, then you would have additive closure, but this time additive inverses wouldn't exist, so the situation doesn't seem remediable.